# Has_many through relation "user_roles" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Hello I try to do a has_many through relation but it's not working as I expect.

Here are my models

```
def User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user_roles, class_name: "UserRole"
 has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

def Role < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user_roles, class_name: "UserRole"
 has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

def UserRole < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :role
end
```

When I do this in rails console

```
User.roles
```

I've got the following error 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "user_roles" does not exist)`

I'm stuck with this error since 2 hours and no google result helped me ...

EDIT:

Here is my migration

```
class CreateUserRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_role do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, type: :uuid 
      t.belongs_to :role, type: :uuid
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you run your migration adding `user_roles` table to DB?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my original post with the migration

Comment: The table is named `user_role`. It should be named `user_roles` to be recognized automatically by rails.

Comment: Ah right ! It's working, feels so stupid to not see that in 2 hours ... . Thanks a lot you are my hero